# Efficient way to implement simple filter with varying coeffients in Python/Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am looking for an efficient way to implement a simple filter with one coefficient that is time-varying and specified by a vector with the same length as the input signal.

The following is a simple implementation of the desired behavior:

```
def myfilter(signal, weights):
    output = np.empty_like(weights)
    val = signal[0]
    for i in range(len(signal)):
        val += weights[i]*(signal[i] - val)
        output[i] = val
    return output

weights = np.random.uniform(0, 0.1, (100,))
signal = np.linspace(1, 3, 100)
output = myfilter(signal, weights)
```

Is there a way to do this more efficiently with numpy or scipy?

Comment: What do you mean by "efficiently"?

Comment: If you mean 'efficiently' by faster computation time, you should look at cython or c implementation of it. There isn't much you can do within python alone for scientific codes. Or, try np.vectorize, pypy, etc... But the gain would be much bigger with c.

Comment: Thanks! With "efficiently", I mean reducing the computation time. I was hoping there is some trick to get a fast pure Python implementation and avoid adding a Cython dependency. I don't see how np.vectorize can help in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can trade in the overhead of the loop for a couple of additional ops:

```
import numpy as np

def myfilter(signal, weights):
    output = np.empty_like(weights)
    val = signal[0]
    for i in range(len(signal)):
        val += weights[i]*(signal[i] - val)
        output[i] = val
    return output

def vectorised(signal, weights):
    wp = np.r_[1, np.multiply.accumulate(1 - weights[1:])]
    sw = weights * signal
    sw[0] = signal[0]
    sws = np.add.accumulate(sw / wp)
    return wp * sws

weights = np.random.uniform(0, 0.1, (100,))
signal = np.linspace(1, 3, 100)
print(np.allclose(myfilter(signal, weights), vectorised(signal, weights)))
```

On my machine the vectorised version is several times faster. It uses a "closed form" solution of your recurrence equation.

Edit: For very long signal / weight (100,000 samples, say) this method doesn't work because of overflow. In that regime you can still save a bit (more than 50% on my machine) using the following trick, which has the added bonus that you needn't solve the recurrence formula, only invert it.

```
from scipy import linalg

def solver(signal, weights):
    rw = 1 / weights[1:]
    v = np.r_[1, rw, 1-rw, 0]
    v.shape = 2, -1
    return linalg.solve_banded((1, 0), v, signal)
```

This trick uses the fact that your recurrence is formally similar to a Gauss elimination on a matrix with only one nonvanishing subdiagonal. It piggybacks on a library function that specialises in doing precisely that.

Actually, quite proud of this one.